# Growth of $n=n(k)$ for which there's a non-trivial solution to $x_1^k+\cdots+x_n^k=y^k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Walter Hayman just asked me the following question. What, if anything, is known about the growth of the function $n(k)$, where $k\geq1$ is an integer, and $n=n(k)\geq2$ is the smallest integer for which there is a non-trivial solution in positive integers to
$$x_1^k+x_2^k+\cdots+x_n^k=y^k.$$

Walter observed that an upper bound for $n(k)$ is $G(k)$ [EDIT: this should probably say $G(k)+1$], the "big $G$" function used as standard notation in discussions of [Waring's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warings_problem). Explicitly, $G(k)$ is the smallest $m$ such that every sufficiently large integer is the sum of at most $m$ $k$th powers; the trick of course is then to choose a sufficiently large $k$th power [EDIT: and then subtract 1.]. Hence $n(k)$ grows at most as fast as $G(k)$, and a fair bit is known about the growth of $G(k)$ (again see the Wikipedia page); for example $G(k)=O(k\log(k))$. We deduce that $n(k)$ is at most $O(k\log(k))$. The question is whether it is possible to do any better.

I would imagine that lower bounds are hopeless -- it was a lot of work to prove that $n(k)\geq3$ for all $k\geq3$, and I am not sure that mathematics is ready to rule out the possibility that there are arbitrarily large integers $k$ such that there are solutions to $a^k+b^k+c^k=d^k$ in positive integers (i.e. that $n(k)\geq4$ for all sufficiently large $k$). But it did not seem unreasonable to hope that there were better upper bounds than the naive approach going via $G(k)$, so I told him I'd ask here.

Comment: I asked about lower bounds at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64649/lower-bounds-on-the-easier-waring-problem

Comment: I don't see why $G(k)$ is an upper bound for $n(k).$ Since every large $k$-th power is already a  $k$-th power, I think they are irrelevant to the value of $G(k).$

Comment: Oh, well. In Unsolved Problems in Number Theory by Richard K. Guy, the closest thing is section D7, page 153 in my edition, very specific, your $x_j = j$ and $y = n+1,$ Rufus Bowen conjectured no solutions. Does anyone know an all positive solution to $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = t^3?$ I don't think $10^3 + 9^3 = 12^3 + 1^3$ counts.

Comment: $3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = 6^3, \; \; \; 1^3 + 6^3 + 8^3 = 9^3, \; \; 3^3 + 10^3 + 18^3 = 19^3, \; \; 7^3 + 14^3 + 17^3 = 20^3$

Comment:  $  19^5 +  43^5 +  46^5 + 47^5 +  67^5 =   72^5 $ 


Comment: Will -- you're right. I guess you can use not $N^k$ but $N^k-1$ in the $G(k)$ result, giving $n(k)\leq G(k)+1$ which is still good enough for what follows. Thanks. I'll fix it.

Comment: Isn't Trevor Wooley on mathoverflow?

Comment: Did your student ever turn in the paper on principal binary quadratic form plus monic cubic one-variable polynomial, the sum representing all numbers?

Comment: @Will: he did, but perhaps here is not the place to discuss it -- email me Will and I'll see if I can find a pdf.

Comment: http://euler.free.fr/ has a lot of numerical examples.

Comment: @Will, isn't D1 more to the point than D7? We have (thanks to Noam Elkies) 3 4th powers that sum to a 4th power, and (thanks to Lander and Parkin) 4 5th powers that sum to a 5th power. Guy says that for $k\ge6$ there is no known sum of $k$ $k$th powers giving a $k$th power. 

Comment: @Gerry, found it, you are right. 