# On the mixed sum of three k-th powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory

Let the set $S_k=\{\pm x^k \pm y^k \pm z^k \ \vert \ x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.
Note that the signs are independently positive or negative.

First of all $S_2 = \mathbb{Z}$ because (see the answers of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1522470/84284)):
$2m = (m+1)^2 - m^2 - 1$ and $2m+1 = (m+3)^2 - (m+2)^2 - 4$

It was proved by congruence computation that  $n \in S_3$ implies $n \not \equiv 4,5  \pmod{9} $, and the converse was conjectured and checked for $n≤1000$ except $33$, $42$, $74$, $114$, $165$, $390$, $579$, $627$, $633$, $732$, $795$, $906$, $921$, and $975$ (see [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-266/S0025-5718-08-02168-6/S0025-5718-08-02168-6.pdf)) (see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/223121/34538)).

*Question*: Is there a similar conjecture and computational results for some small $k>3$?

We find by congruence computation that:

- $n \in S_4$ implies $n \not \equiv  4,5,6  \pmod{8} $
- $n \in S_5$ implies $n \not \equiv  4,5,6,7  \pmod{11} $
- $n \in S_6$ implies
  $n \not \equiv   4,5  \pmod{7} $
  $n \not \equiv   4,5,6  \pmod{8} $
  $n \not \equiv  4,5,6,7 \pmod{9} $
  $n \not \equiv  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 \pmod{13} $
- $n \in S_7$ implies
  $n \not \equiv   8, 9, 20, 21  \pmod{29} $
  $n \not \equiv   10, 16, 17, 26, 27, 33  \pmod{43} $
  $n \not \equiv  4, 9, 15, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 34, 40, 45 \pmod{49} $

and  the converse of each point could be conjectured.

*Remark:* this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/64649/34538) states that assuming the generalized abc conjecture, $S_k$ should have zero density for $k>18$, which prevents, in this case, a conjecture describing this set by finitely many congruences, as above.

Comment: I think at least the problem for $k = 3$ is hard;
however the basic heuristics suggests that for $k > 3$,
the density of $S_k$ will be zero.

Comment: @StefanKohl: the congruence computation suggests a density of $7/11$ for $k=5$, which heuristics suggests a zero density?

Comment: Regarding zero density - can one even show that $x^{n}+y^{m}$ has zero density for any $n\neq m\geq 1$, not both even?

Comment: @StefanKohl: That heuristic is not accurate as $x,y$ and $z$ can take negative values. Other than using congruence's, it's not clear how to determine whether or not $n$ has infinitely many representations of the form $n=x^5+y^5+z^5$.

Comment: @EricNaslund: My feeling would be that that makes obtaining results more difficult, but that it doesn't really affect the heuristics -- but I haven't thought about this or obtained numerical evidence or whatever, so perhaps you are right.

Comment: Related question posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524797/can-a-sum-of-three-fifth-power-of-integers-be-8

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** This answers previous revision, quite different question.

---

Let $k = 5$. I think a *single* representation outside
your forbidden congruences would violate "Vojta's more general abc conjecture".

In [A more general abc conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806171), p. 7 Paul Vojta conjectures:

---

If $x_0,\ldots x_{n-1}$ are nonzero coprime integers satisfing $x_0 + \cdots x_{n-1}=0$

$$ \max\{|x_0|,\ldots |x_{n-1}|\} \le C \prod_{p\mid x_0 \cdots x_{n-1}}p^{1+\epsilon}\qquad (1) $$

for all $x_0 , \ldots, x_{n-1}$ as above **outside a proper Zariski-closed subset**.

---

Let $n=2^m 11^l$, where $m,l$ are coprime to $5$ and $m,l$ are coprime.

$m,l$ can be arbitrary large. The radical of $n$ is constant
and we have $n=2^m 11^l=x^5+y^5+z^5$.

By Vojta's conjecture, as $m,l$ vary as above, every single solution
must be on proper Zariski-closed subset, which appears highly unlikely to
me.

To ensure coprimality, clear the gcd.

$2$ can be replaced by any other positive natural
and $n$ large, but with small radical satisfying your congruences
will in general work, unless clearing the gcd solves it.

---

Similar argument for larger $k$ and $n$ sufficiently larger
than its radical would contradict also the n-conjecture.

The [n-conjecture](http://cr.yp.to/bib/1994/browkin.pdf)
is a generalization of abc and basically says that the if
$a_1 + \ldots + a_n=0$, no proper subsum vanishes and $a_i$
are coprime, then the radical of $a_1\cdots a_n$ can't be
too small (without exceptional set).

Comment: For $k$ odd it is the same question, I've allowed the mixed sums for extending to $k$ even.

Comment: I try to understand your argument for $k=5$. Anyway, if (up to Vojta's conjecture) it is working for the previous revision then it is also working for the current revision because $5$ is odd and for any revision we have $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Can you extend your argument to $k=4$ for the current revision?

Comment: For helping me to understand, could you explain why examples like: $3⋅11=0^5+1^5+2^5$ or $6257⋅11=6^5+11^5+(−10)^5$, are not concerned by your argument (you wrote << $2$ can be replaced by any other positive natural...>>)?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux These don't work. As written, n must be of the form 2^m 11^l (or similar) with 
the radical of $n$ much smaller than $n$. The radical is the product of the primes factors, without multiplicities. In your examples $n$ is squarefree and $n=rad(n)$, which is allowed by both conjectures. Basically to work, $n$ must be large and $rad(n)=22$, which is constant.

Comment: Ok so we have $x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$ with $x_1 = x^5, x_2 = y^5, x_3 = z^5$, and $x_0 = -n = -2^m11^l$, with $m,l$ large enough as above. The inequality of Vojta's conjecture deals with $\vert x_0 \vert , \vert x_1 \vert, \vert x_2 \vert, \vert x_3 \vert $, and $rad(x_0x_1x_2x_3)$, which means that it does not deal *only* with $\vert x_0 \vert$ and $rad(x_0)$. So even if $rad(n)$ is much smaller than $n$, $rad(x_0x_1x_2x_3)$ could be very big, and I don't understand the argument in this case.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Yes, indeed the radical can be very big. But it must be sufficiently small to $T=max(|x|^5,|y|^5,|z|^5)$. Assume $x$ is largest in absolute value then $T=|x|^5$, the radical of $n$ ($x_0$ in your notation is constant), so the whole radical of the product is less than $C |x|^3$, which is significantly smaller than $|x|^5$

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux For the n-conjecture, the radical must be significantly smaller than $T$, so just increase $n$, avoiding any exceptional set.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux I mean both conjectures imply the radical can't be too small compared to $|x|^n$.

Comment: Ok I better understand this part, now in what it is << highly unlikely >> that << every single solution must be on proper Zariski-closed subset >> ? I note that your argument works only for the case $k>3$ because $C \vert x \vert^3$ must be << significantly smaller than >> $\vert x \vert^k$. Do you think your Zariski belief also relevant for the case $k=4$ ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux This is my belief. To avoid exceptional set, use larger $k$ and the n-conjecture. For $k=4$ I believe you can't express numbers with sufficiently small radical, though there are polynomial identities which when specialized give exceptional set.

Comment: Perhaps your answer would get more upvotes if you motivate your Zariski belief by some evidences.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux the Zariski argument is not needed for the n-conjecture, which IMHO is at least equally believed.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, we can apply the $n$-conjecture only for $k$ large ($k>18$ by [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/q/64649/34538)), but I ask for small $k$. What I call your "Zariski belief" is not the Vojta's conjecture itself but your sentence << ... which appears highly unlikely to me >>.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux I think $k=10$ is enough since $x^{10} \gg C |x|^9$ and in the n-conjecture the exponent is $3$.